Star Wars vehicle identification
We are trying to identify this vehicle because the instructions were lost. We don’t remember which one it is, only that it is Star Wars. Completed portion is grey with 2 white seats red accents. I have 2 bags of parts not opened that I think also go with it.


Howdy Melody, welcome to Bricks StackExchange.  It will be difficult to answer your question without a picture of how far you've gotten in building.   There are hundreds of Star Wars sets to choose from.  A picture of the remaining parts could help too.

For the unopened bags, please check out the process outlined here and edit your question with any issues you encounter during your search.

Searching for sets that include at least 2 black 4x1 curved slopes and at least 2 white 2x1 tiles with handlebar quickly points to set 75083 "AT-DP".
The instructions for the set do match the subassembly:

